# SQL Server ADO.Net retrieve error information from sql script

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling

I am working on a project where we have to query an old SQL Server 2000 database (PeopleSoft, if you must know). The query returns a resultset. If we were on a newer database, I would use stored procedures and error handling (e.g. @ErrNo, @ErrMsg, Try/Catch) to get what I want.

However, we are on SQL Server 2000 and we are NOT allowed to use stored procedures, so we are left with only using dynamic SQL queries and scripts. We are currently using ADO.Net (e.g. DbCommand and Execute methods on it) to get our resultset.

What I'd like to do is put more error handling / validation in our sql scripts and return messages to our .Net code. (e.g. input value not valid, row not found, etc.)

Does anyone know how to do this under these contraints? If there are no easy ways to do this, can you recommend some alternatives? e.g.

1. ask the DBA to create a specialized message / logging table for us
   and in our scripts, write to that table
   and in our code, read that table
2. break up our code / scripts into multiple steps and call it from our .Net code (would we then have to use transactions?)
3. etc. etc.? Really banging my head here...

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures have little to do with what (I feel) you trying to achieve. Even if you have Error handling in stored procedure, you still going to send invalid data to get error handled. Seems, what you need is better "before DB call" validation.

What you can do to improve your situation is to utilize Ado.net to great extent. Specifically - use `DataTables`. You can load schema and it will create your `DataTable` in shape of your Sql Table. Check the properties of the `DataTable` `Column` object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn_properties%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

If you try to insert invalid data into this table first, it will error out and you will be able to create specific error handling.

Also, you can (and should) replace dynamic sql with parametrized query. This is recommended way and will improve performance.

Instead of :

```
"select * from customer where id = " + custId.ToString()
```

You should do:

```
"select * from customer where id = @1"
```

Then, when you create your command object, you will add a parameter. This is good for Sql Server performance.

While for you, `DataTable`will be line of defense against sending erroneous code to server.

Another way is writing entirely your own data validation logic based on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Another way is to have really strict data input validation.

Normally, systems have both, input validation and data layer validation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but my situation isn't quite like that. For example, we have a business that when a user inserts a new row of data, it must be active/effective' as of today, and not future dated. This is not enforced in UI or DB. So, during my import/integration logic, I have to handle three scenarios: 1) get the expected record that was just inserted, 2) no record found (unexpected error situation), or 3) row exists, but is invalid and should NOT be returned. I need to distinguish between the latter two scenarios. This is just one common example.

Comment: No problem - you need to create business layer where you lock your record in transaction. Request the record: If you find no record- throw `RecordNotFoundException`. Inspect the record for errors and if problem - throw `RecordInvalidException`. ANd to make sure this is not done concurrently, there is a trick for this. You create a DB table, called `CriticalSectionLock`. In there, you can add some rows, for example `CustomerRecLock`. You lock that record in transaction and until you release it, no other code will access record validation logic.Basically, what you think stored Proc you need BLL